# Alternative for MC14543B

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, alternatives

I'm following a tutorial that use a MC14543B chip.
The chip is defined as "Bcd-to-7 Segment Latch/decoder/driver"

Datasheet is here: http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/343/MC14543B-pdf.php

Any advice ? What do you use to control 7 segments from the status of only 4 pins ?

Edit:
I was asked for a Schema where the BCD to 7 segment is being used:

[image: MC14543B]
<sub>(source: [siteduzero.com](https://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/405001_406000/405982.png))</sub>

Comment: Why do you want an alternative? What 'advice' are you seeking?

Comment: Because I can't find where to buy it in Canada... :(

Comment: It would probably be very easy to recreate this chip's logic with a small CPLD from any vendor, provided that you're not afraid of dealing with that toolchain. Those parts might be easier to source.

Comment: Octopart shows 3000 pieces in stock at Future Electronics Canada.

Comment: A schematic or link to the tutorial you are following might help.

Comment: @Passerby CPLD is too complicated for my current skill ( and more expensive) / I added a schematic / I didn't know about octopart, how do you search canada ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a 4543 CMOS IC, different manufacturers use different prefixes. RCA (the founder, for what it's worth, although TI has this now) would call it CD4543B. SGS / ST use 'HEF'. Motorola/On semi use MC(1), as in this case. Other manufacturers use different names yet.

On ebay or digikey or.. wherever, just search for '4543'.

For what it's worth though, 4543 is designed for LCDs and has piddly little output current. CD4511 is better for driving LEDs, as it can sink 25mA instead of.. a couple.